# String replace regex doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to delete all console.*(*) from string or text and this code doesnt work, why?

```
var str = "console.log('test')";
var pattern = /console\..*\(.*\);/gm;
console.log(str.replace(pattern, ""));
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gzFPopi1qdd6PYZz2urM?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because in your test string there is no `;` however regexp expects one. Just make it optional with `?`:

```
var pattern = /console\..*?\(.*?\);?/gm;
```

Also make sure the match is not greedy with `.*?`.

Check the test demo below.

```js
var str = "some string console.log('test'); and console.log(123) \
console.log('123', 12, 'asd'); \
test";

alert( str.replace(/console\..*?\(.*?\);?/gm, '') );
```